# Desktop applications cannot connect to the internet

Tags: windows-7, networking, socks-proxy

I've been using Shadowsocks 4.1.2 for a while on my Windows 7. It was set to run on startup. Recently I've turned it off and for some reason I can't seem to use any of my desktop applications to access the internet. Turning it back on again does not fix the issue. Only work-around I currently have is changing the settings to PAC from global, which fixes connection issues. Some apps which I cannot use are as follows;

Spotify, Twitch, TukUI, TSM Client, Battle.Net client works but can't access the internet, can launch games, Steam.

I can however run World of Warcraft, and also use Firefox.

I tried resetting netsh winsock to no avail. I use DNS servers from OpenNIC but resetting/removing them does nothing. Any suggestions?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Late answer, but it seems for some reason proxy settings in Internet Explorer were not getting cleared.

Resetting those settings fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The latest windows update(KB4480970/KB4480960) has been known to cause some networking issues. If you've installed this update, try uninstalling it.

Failing that, there are some fixes you can attempt [here](https://borncity.com/win/2019/01/09/netzwerk-issues-with-updates-kb4480970-and-kb4480960/) and [here](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3332202/microsoft-windows/patch-tuesday-updates-for-win7-kb-4480970-and-kb-4480960-knock-out-networking.html).

Comment: sadly removing said updates did not fix my issue :(